# Unable to start glassfish server in ubuntu 16

Tags: jakarta-ee, ubuntu-16.04, glassfish-4

I am unable to start my glassfish server in ubuntu 16. The error I am seeing is 
"GlassFish requires Java SE version 6.  Your JDK is version 0"

Now here are my settings :

```
JAVA_HOME          : /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle
Entry in asenv.conf :  AS_JAVA=/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle
 java -version      : java version 9.0.4
                    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
                    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

I  have mentioned Java home in the asenv, still glassfish is not recognizing and throwing error.
What configuration I need to do to get my glassfish working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple - Glassfish doesn't support Java 9 yet, not even the most recent version 5.0.

You need to install Java 8 and use it to run GlassFish.

Comment: AS_JAVA="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"              ..This one worked for me